# C# equivalent of VB DLL function declaration (InternetSetOption)?

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is the C# equivalent of this VB code?

```
Private Declare Auto Function InternetSetOption Lib "wininet.dll" (ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Here it is](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet/internetsetoption.html?diff=y):

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool InternetSetOption(
    IntPtr hInternet, 
    int dwOption, 
    IntPtr lpBuffer, 
    int dwBufferLength
);
```

Comment: Also, using System.Runtime.InteropServices;