# C# equivalent of VB DLL function declaration coming back with 'Attempted to read or write protected memory' error

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, vba, dll

If my VBA code is:

```
Private Declare Function pca Lib "mc.dll" Alias "_pca@40" (ByVal n As Long, ByVal nsim As Long, ByVal nbucket As Long, ByVal percent As Double, ByRef cor As Double, ByRef result As Double, ByRef evalue As Double, ByRef evector As Double, ByRef np As Long) As Long
```

Would my C# code be (see below)?

```
[DllImport("mc.dll", EntryPoint = "_pca@40")]
private static extern long pca(long n, long maxsize, long nbucket, double percent, double[] cor, double[] result, double[] d1, double[] v1, long np);
```

From Visual studio, I am trying to use a C++ function in mc.dll but keep getting a "attempted to read or write protected memory" error.

Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?  The VBA program is able to access the DLL fine but my C# is not.

I Followed the format of the previously asked question from the link below, I wrote my code but kept getting an error. [C# equivalent of VB DLL function declaration (InternetSetOption)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946486/c-sharp-equivalent-of-vb-dll-function-declaration-internetsetoption)

Comment: A VBA long is 32-bits a C# long is 64-bits  ...

Comment: You may gain some insights by reading "CLR Inside Out
Marshaling between Managed and Unmanaged Code" by Yi Zhang and Xiaoying Guo.  Unfortunately the original MSDN link is no longer available, but you can view it via web.archive.org at http://web.archive.org/web/20090211060921/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Your VB defintion contains `ByRef` values that you are not passing by reference in your C# P/Invoke definition.  Also you appear to be passing double arrays instead of ByRef doubles in the VB6.  Finally as a VB6 long is a 32 bit type, which is the same as a C# int.

So the definition should be:

```
[DllImport("mc.dll", EntryPoint = "_pca@40")]
private static extern int pca(int n, int maxsize, int nbucket, double percent, ref double cor, ref double result, ref double d1, ref double v1, ref int np);
```